# Changing values in pandas without for loop python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a column DateOfDeparture. I want to change all the dates to weekDay.

How can I do it? I have tried this :

```
df_train['DateOfDeparture']=datetime.strptime(df_train['DateOfDeparture'], '%Y-%M-%d').date().weekday()
```

The string in the column is in %Y-%M-%d format.

The error I take is strptime() argument 1 must be string, not Series.

Comment: You cannot use `strptime` directly on a series object. Either iterate over every row which are date strings using `apply` and then use it, or I'd prefer a more vectorized `pd.to_datetime(df_train['DateOfDeparture']).dt.weekday` which performs really fast over large number of rows. Also, you'd want to change the directive from `%M`(minute) to `%m`(month) to suit your purpose.

Comment: just to emphasize the previous comment, you almost always will want to convert a datetime-string to a pandas datetime with `to_datetime` before doing anything else.  It will make many subsequent steps much easier.  http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html